# Cannot access site through http from https server

Tags: http, https

I have a https site say with url www.example.com. On this server, I've an application which is decoupled in front-end and back-end. The front-end is a gwt application and the back-end is a REST interface.

To call the rest interface, the front-end uses https, say with a url like https://www.example.com/api

however, when I'm trying to call the front-end using http://www.example.com, it is not making the call to rest interface when i'm using https://www.example.com, it is ok. Can someone explain the reason of this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com` are different URIs and nothing requires that a web server serve up the same content for both. Presumably your server isn't configured to do so.

Comment: Assuming you have sufficient rights on the server, yes. The specifics depend on the HTTP server software you are running.